# Construct a connected graph where each edge precisely lies on $k$ triangles.

Tags: graph-theory

I try to construct a connected graph where each edge precisely lies on $k$ triangles. Of course, for $k=1$, we can replace each edge of a path with a triangle.  4-connected maximal planar graphs are examples for $k=2.$ So, for $k=3$ and beyond, how do we construct it?

---

**Further problem.**

Construct minimum (minimum number of vertices) connected graphs  such that each edge precisely lies on $k$ triangles.

Comment: I would probably start with a tetrahedron (but in $k$ dimensions), and try find a way to project it onto a 2D plane, and this should work since a graph being planar isn't a requirement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is simply just a complete graph with $k+2$ vertices. In other words, a $K_{k+2}$.

Consider any edge in that complete graph. We see that one triangle can be formed for every other vertex (that is, not part of the original edge we chose). We can see that there are $k$ vertices left over, which corresponds to $k$ different triangles, and exactly $k$ different triangles.

Thus, we are done.

(It is also the projection of a $k$-dimensional simplice projected onto the 2D plane)

Comment: Yes. I see. Perhaps we need to impose constraints or consider examples with minimum edges for fixed orders. Only when asked in that way does the question become challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Special case solution for $k=3$
[image]

Comment: yes... this is the 5 cell projected onto the 2D plane :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell

Comment: Thanks for the link, @AaaLol_dude ! I had never heard of a 5-cell before